File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Restrict
I have some issue with the line
calendar = calendar.Restrict(f'[Start] >= {begin.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')} AND [End] <= {end.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')}')
in my code.
Something is there wrong but I couldn't find something.
Complete code:
import os
import datetime
import requests
import json
import google.auth
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import win32com.client

# Konfiguration
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'credentials.json'
TOKEN_FILE = 'token.json'

def authenticate_google():
    creds = None
    token_dir = os.path.dirname(TOKEN_FILE)
    if token_dir and not os.path.exists(token_dir):
        os.makedirs(token_dir)

    if os.path.exists(TOKEN_FILE):
        if os.path.getsize(TOKEN_FILE) > 0: 
            try:
                creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKEN_FILE, SCOPES)
            except (json.JSONDecodeError, ValueError) as e:
                print(f"Fehler beim Laden der JSON-Datei: {e}")
                creds = None
        else:
            print("Token-Datei ist leer.")
            creds = None

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        try:
            with open(TOKEN_FILE, 'w') as token_file:
                token_file.write(creds.to_json())
        except OSError as e:
            print(f"Fehler beim Schreiben der Token-Datei: {e}")
            raise
    return creds

def get_google_calendar_events(service):
    now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
    return events_result.get('items', [])

def get_outlook_calendar_events():
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    calendar = outlook.Folders.Item("wiesinger.markus@gmx.at").Items

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    begin = now - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    end = now + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

    calendar = calendar.Restrict(f'[Start] >= {begin.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')} AND [End] <= {end.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')}')
    
    events = []
    for item in calendar:
        events.append({
            'subject': item.Subject,
            'start': item.Start.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
            'end': item.End.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
            'description': item.Body,
            'location': item.Location
        })
    return events

def add_event_to_google(service, event):
    event_body = {
        'summary': event['subject'],
        'start': {
            'dateTime': event['start'],
            'timeZone': 'UTC',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': event['end'],
            'timeZone': 'UTC',
        },
        'description': event.get('description', ''),
        'location': event.get('location', '')
    }
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event_body).execute()
    print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))

def add_event_to_outlook(event):
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    try:
        calendar = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(9).Items
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Fehler beim Zugriff auf den Standardkalender: {e}")
        return
    
    try:
        new_event = calendar.Add(1)

        new_event.Subject = event.get('summary', 'Kein Betreff')

        start_time = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        end_time = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))

        new_event.Start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
        new_event.End = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

        new_event.Body = event.get('description', '')
        new_event.Location = event.get('location', '')
        
        new_event.Save()
        print(f"Event hinzugefügt: {new_event.Subject}")
        
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"Fehlender Schlüssel im Event-Objekt: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Allgemeiner Fehler beim Hinzufügen des Events zu Outlook: {e}")

def sync_calendars():
    google_creds = authenticate_google()
    google_service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=google_creds)

    google_events = get_google_calendar_events(google_service)
    outlook_events = get_outlook_calendar_events()

    for event in google_events:
        add_event_to_outlook(event)
    
    for event in outlook_events:
        add_event_to_google(google_service, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sync_calendars()


I would like to get outlook event to sync them with my Google account.
